# How to show my twitter feeds on a static webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter

I have a static HTML webpage which is not capable to run php or connect with MySQL. I used this page to create my personal home page. I am very interested to list my last 20 tweets in this page. Is there an easy way to fetch those tweets from twitter.com and then show them in my static homepage ?

I am open to any technology that work best for this job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look [here.](https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/) (You'll need to be logged into Twitter.)

This should do the job for you. The good news is it's all HTML!

Good luck...

Answer (score 2):

There are many widgets available for doing just this on the client side, in html. Some are even from Twitter: https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines